# How to send 'Mark as Important' mail using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-email, email

I need your views as i don't know is it possible or not.

I want some emails send by my application should `'Mark as Important'` so that when end user receive this mail in there `Evolution/Outlook` they should know the importance of email.

Currently when i marked any email using evolution as `'Mark as Important'` it changes the colour of mail subject and other fields to `red`.

Answer (score 8):

Both other answers are correct, but the thing is, Outlook uses a non-standard header for signaling importance. It's called X-Priority, so you have to include it in your outgoing mail. You can also include "X-MSMail-Priority: High" for older Outlooks.

```
def notification
  mail({
      :to => 'email@example.com',
      :subject => 'My subject',
      :from => 'me@somewhere.com',
      'Importance' => 'high',
      'X-Priority' => '1'}) do |format|
    format.text
    format.html
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => 'no-reply@example.com',
          :return_path => 'system@example.com'

  def welcome(recipient)
    @account = recipient
    mail(:to => recipient.email_address_with_name,
         :bcc => ["bcc@example.com", "Order Watcher <watcher@example.com>"],
         :subject => "No way!",
         :importance => "High") # <======
    end
  end
```

Comment: hey steenslag it's not working for me .........will you please give me more details of this?

Comment: I used headers['X-priority'] = 1 and it works for on outlook express but not on an evolution as Evolution will ignore the message priority, because it assumes that the recipient should decide whether the message is important or not.

Answer (score 1):

The [MIME RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#page-32%20MIME%20RFC) lists importance as a header that can be sent with MIME email. The values that can be used are high, normal or low. To send an email with an adjusted importance, use an API that allows you to either set the importance via an API method, or one that allows you to set individual headers (such as [TMail](http://i.loveruby.net/en/man/tmail/mail.html)).

I don't know Ruby, so I can't give you an example, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.